# What if Staphylococcus Aureus are extinct?

Tags: bacteriology

What if Staphylococcus Aureus are extinct?

Can it be good for human or bad for human?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: thats a homework question isnt it.

Comment: Of course not. I have nose infection and it was caused by my razor. I am curious how I can prevent bacteria in this kind of situation (when I am not protected by skin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost entirely parasitic and has not physiological or ecological effects that could not be replaced easily by another bacterium. It is responsible for immeasurably more infections that protections of humans, therefore it is a disease vector, not a beneficial bacterium.

If it went extinct, humans may suffer from increased population pressure, that would be the only worry.

Comment: I know this has been closed already, but could you please provide a reference?

Comment: There are millions of references, i.e. A large proportion of the population (60%) harbours S. aureus intermittently, and the strains change with varying frequencies. Such persons are called intermittent carriers. Finally, a minority of the people (20%) almost never carry S... it's not possible to find a study about benefits of aureus, it's always benefits of treatments of the desease.

Comment: So this is a very helpful answer. It means scientists don't have to hesitate to kill S.aureus as many as they can.

Comment: thanks, the over use of antibiotics is what creates super resistant variants. excess and low hygiene and un-natural human cities and social structures probably cause most S. aureus problems.